# Lottery Expected Value Question

Tags: probability

Background: The Daily 3 game is a daily game, drawn every day except
for Saturday and Sunday. It consists of three sets of balls, each numbered
from $0$ through $8$ ($9$ is omitted due to its visual similarity to
$6$). One ball is drawn from each set giving a $3$-digit winning number.
All numbers must be in the correct order to win. A ticket costs $\$1$.  The prize for getting all three numbers correct is $\$500$.

Question:  Assuming each possible outcome is equally likely to appear, how
much money, on average, will the Agency receive from each Daily
3 ticket, after paying winners?

I think this is an expected value question. Here is my work so far:
$X$ = Agency's profit.  Then 
$$E(X)= P(\text{Grand Prize})\cdot(-500 + 1) + P(\text{Losing Ticket})\cdot(1).$$

$P(\text{Grand Prize}) = 1/729.\;$
$P(\text{Losing Ticket}) = 728/729.\;$  So $$E(X) = 1/729 \cdot (-500 + 1) + 728/729 \cdot 1 = .314. $$

Answer: Agency's Profit is $.31$ cents per ticket (this seems too low, I think I did something wrong)

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Lotteries don't need to make a large profit per ticket. They rely on selling  *lots* of tickets.

Comment: To be fussy, profit per ticket is 31 cents or $\$0.31.$  Two edits going on simultaneously. Not sure whether error is due to OP or editing. Also, many state lotteries make more like 50 cents on the dollar, so 31 cents may be at the low end, but not incredible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the expected value of this lottery that costs 50 cents per ticket?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659156/whats-the-expected-value-of-this-lottery-that-costs-50-cents-per-ticket)